# IntelliJ IDEA running Android Native Activity application

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-ndk, native-activity

I am trying to run the native activity sample that comes with the Android NDK. I remember it used to run fine with Eclipse but with IntelliJ IDEA I always get an error saying "Default Activity not found" when I select "Launch default Activity" from the run configuration dialog. If I try to enter the custom activity name like "android.app.NativeActivity" it again cannot find it.

Am I stuck with Eclipse or is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: If you have the Ultimate Edition you should really contact JetBrains. They provide good support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no support for launching NDK Activity right now, please [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).